# SQL text manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

This is how the data looks like and I need to separate the genre from each row and as you can see there is many genres in each row. I want this to do in SQL. Any recommendations ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, my recommendation is: Don't store the data like this. You have a *relational database*. Store the data in separate columns. And make this a table where you have one genre per row.

Comment: And [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: YEs thats how I want to store it and that's what I'm working on

Comment: You can write a recursive query to extract genre by genre and for each genre the ID. But honestly, I would just select all the data in an app with a good old-fashioned programming language, loop through the rows, extract the data, send insert statements to the DBMS.

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Comment: @balajirajaram *don't* store data like this. Just don't. This breaks the most basic design rule and as a result you can't query, modify, sort or index the data. Since the string is JSON you can parse it but any kind of operation will be extremely slow, forcing you to process the entire table just to find a single value

Comment: @balajirajaram `thats how I want to store it` why? There's no "Because I want it" in this case. Hammering a screw is possible but destroys the screw and wall. Storing data like that takes *more* space than using another table too, as storing numbers as text takes a lot more space, never mind the useless separators.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you have *almost* valid JSON, you need to change the `'` single quotes to `"` double quotes

```
REPLACE(genres, '''', '"')
```

You can then use `OPENJSON` to break out the data into separate rows

```
OPENJSON(REPLACE(genres, '''', '"')) WITH (id int, name varchar(100))
```

So you can store distinct genres in a table, and have a separate many to many join table, like this

```sql
INSERT Genre (Id, Name)
SELECT DISTINCT j.id, j.name
FROM Movie AS m
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(m.genres, '''', '"'))
    WITH (id int, name varchar(100)) AS j;

INSERT GenreMovie (GenreId, MovieId)
SELECT j.id, m.id
FROM Movie AS m
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(m.genres, '''', '"'))
    WITH (id int) AS j;
```

You can then remove the `genres` column from `Movie` because it is not the correct way to store such data. The above tables are correct and far easier to query.

Comment: I think you need to stress that storing data like this should never be done and the consequences: impossible to query, index, sort or modify, scanning the entire table to get a single value. And taking more space than a lookup table because numbers are stored as text and the separators